# Spring ROO Dynamic Menu

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo

I m new at spring roo. I don't know how to create Dynamic menu in spring roo project. And if Dynamic menu add ons available. How can I use this add on?
Thank for your time

Comment: Dynamic menu — what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default roo menu.jspx is dynamic. In case you mean dynamic as animated menu, just feel free to try including your own javascript based menu implementation.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

Build your own, Spring Roo is not a replacement for software developers.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-ROO doesn't support this out of the box. These kind of requirements are very specific to the kind of application you are building.

Comment: does spring-addon web-menu include dynamic menu?and how can I get sample code to create dynamic menu for roo